# Kubernetes Persistent Volume Access Modes: ReadWriteOnce vs ReadOnlyMany vs ReadWriteMany

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

As per this official [document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes), Kubernetes Persistent Volumes support three types of access modes.

1. ReadOnlyMany
2. ReadWriteOnce
3. ReadWriteMany

The given definitions of them in the document is very high-level. It would be great if someone can explain them in little more detail along with some examples of different use cases where we should use one vs other.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You should use `ReadWriteX` when you plan to have Pods that will need to *write* to the volume, and not only *read* data from the volume.

You should use `XMany` when you want the ability for Pods to access the given volume while those workloads are running on different nodes in the Kubernetes cluster.  These Pods may be multiple replicas belonging to a Deployment, or may be completely different Pods. There are many cases where it's desirable to have Pods running on different nodes, for instance if you have multiple Pod replicas for a single Deployment, then having them run on different nodes can help ensure some amount of continued availability even if one of the nodes fails or is being updated.

If you don't use `XMany`, but you do have multiple Pods that need access to the given volume, that will force Kubernetes to schedule all those Pods to run on whatever node the volume gets mounted to first, which could overload that node if there are too many such pods, and can impact the availability of Deployments whose Pods need access to that volume as explained in the previous paragraph.

So putting all that together:

- If you need to write to the volume, and you may have multiple Pods needing to write to the volume where you'd prefer the flexibility of those Pods being scheduled to different nodes, and `ReadWriteMany` is an option given the volume plugin for your K8s cluster, use `ReadWriteMany`.
- If you need to write to the volume but either you don't have the requirement that multiple pods should be able to write to it, or `ReadWriteMany` simply isn't an available option for you, use `ReadWriteOnce`.
- If you only need to read from the volume, and you may have multiple Pods needing to read from the volume where you'd prefer the flexibility of those Pods being scheduled to different nodes, and `ReadOnlyMany` is an option given the volume plugin for your K8s cluster, use `ReadOnlyMany`.
- If you only need to read from the volume but either you don't have the requirement that multiple pods should be able to read from it, or `ReadOnlyMany` simply isn't an available option for you, use `ReadWriteOnce`. In this case, you want the volume to be read-only but the limitations of your volume plugin have forced you to choose `ReadWriteOnce` (there's no `ReadOnlyOnce` option). As a good practice, consider the `containers.volumeMounts.readOnly` setting to `true` in your Pod specs for volume mounts corresponding to volumes that are intended to be read-only.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks

Comment: Great explanation.

Comment: Still some questions:  (1) how do you get content on a readonlymany volume? There must be one pod that can write on it. But different pods cannot access the same volume with different access modes.

Comment: (2) If a pod with access to a readwriteonce volume is rolled over, can the new pod access the volume while the old pod is still claiming it?

Answer (score 12):

###### 1. ReadOnlyMany – the volume can be mounted read-only by many nodes

- By this method, **multiple pods** running on multiple nodes can use a
  **single volume** and **read** data.
- If a pod mounts a volume with ReadOnlyMany access mode, other pod can
  mount it and perform only read operation. GCP supports this from GKE version [1.22](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/persistent-volumes/readonlymany-disks#requirements).
- This means a volume can be mounted on one or many nodes of your
  Kubernetes cluster and you can only perform read operation.
- You have one pod is running on node and you are reading stored file
  from volume. While on same volume you can not perform writes.
- As it's **ReadOnlyMany**, if your pod is scheduled to another node, then
  also volume and data will be available to perform read operation.

###### 2. ReadWriteMany – the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes

- By this method, **multiple pods** running on multiple **nodes** can
  use a **single volume** and **read/write** data.
- If a pod mounts a volume with ReadWriteMany access mode, other pod
  can also mount it.
- This means the volume can be mounted on one or many node of your
  Kubernetes cluster and you can perform both, read and write
  operation.
- You have one pod running on a node and you are reading & writing the
  stored file from the volume.
- As it's ReadWriteMany if your pod schedule to another node then also
  the volume and data will be available there to perform read/write
  operation.
- for this, you can use NFS ([MinIO](https://min.io/), [GlusterFS](https://www.gluster.org/)) or [EFS](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/)
  filesystem also.

###### 3. ReadWriteOnce – the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node

- If a pod mounts a volume with ReadWriteOnce access mode, no other pod
  can mount it. In GCE (Google Compute Engine) the only allowed modes
  are ReadWriteOnce and ReadOnlyMany. So either one pod mounts the
  volume ReadWrite, or one or more pods mount the volume **ReadOnlyMany**.
- This means the volume can be mounted on `only` one node of your
  kubernetes cluster and you can only perform read operation.
- You have one pod running on node and you are reading stored file from
  volume. While on same volume you cannot perform writes.
- As it's **ReadWriteOnce** if your pod is scheduled to another node then
  may mossible volume will be attached to the node and you can not get
  access of data there.

Comment: I could not understand that why `ReadWriteOnce` volume can only be read by one pod on one node? If it says `Write` in the name then why not it's writable by one node?

Comment: Multiple pods can write to the same persistent volume referenced by a common persistent volume claim, even in RWO mode. Moreover, on local storage volumes, multiple pods on different nodes can write to the same PV, because a PV in this case might be a single logical entity pointing to different physical disks attached to nodes. All in all, the exact behavior of access modes will vary between different PV types, Kubernetes official documentation isn't very clear on this.

Answer (score 6):

In Kubernetes you provision storage either statically(using a storage class) or dynamically (Persistent Volume). Once the storage is available to bound and claimed, you need to configure it in what way your Pods or Nodes are connecting to the storage (a persistent volume). That could be configured in below four modes.

1. **ReadOnlyMany (ROX)**

In this mode multiple pods running on different Nodes could connect to the storage and carry out **read** operation.

2. **ReadWriteMany (RWX)**

In this mode multiple pods running on different Nodes could connect to the storage and carry out **read and write** operation.

3. **ReadWriteOnce  (RWO)**

In this mode **multiple pods running in only one Node** could connect to the storage and carry out **read and write** operation.

4. **ReadWriteOncePod (RWOP)**

In this mode the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single Pod. Use ReadWriteOncePod access mode if you want to ensure that only one pod across whole cluster can read that PVC or write to it. This is only supported for CSI volumes and Kubernetes version 1.22+.

Folow the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) to get more insight.