# kubernetes PVCs sharing a single PV?

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean

I am trying to deploy a persistentvolume for 3 pods to work on and i want to use the cluster's node storage i.e. not an external storage like ebs spin off.

To achieve the above i did the following experiment's -

1) I applied only the below PVC resource defined below -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: pv1
  name: pv1
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
status: {}
```

This spin's up a storage set by default storageclass, which in my case was digital ocean's volume. So it created a 1Gi volume.

2) Created a PV resource and PVC resource like below -

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

---

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: pv1
  name: pv1
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
status: {}
```

Post this i see my claim is bound.

```
    pavan@p1:~$ kubectl get pvc
    NAME        STATUS   VOLUME           CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
    pv1   Bound    task-pv-volume   10Gi       RWO            manual         2m5s
    pavan@p1:~$ kubectl get pv
    NAME             CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM               STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
    task-pv-volume   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    default/pv1   manual                  118m
pavan@p1:~$ kubectl describe pvc
Name:          pv1
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  manual
Status:        Bound
Volume:        task-pv-volume
Labels:        io.kompose.service=pv1
Annotations:   kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                 {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"PersistentVolumeClaim","metadata":{"annotations":{},"creationTimestamp":null,"labels":{"io.kompose.service":"mo...
               pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      10Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    <none>
Events:
  Type     Reason              Age                 From                         Message
  ----     ------              ----                ----                         -------
  Warning  ProvisioningFailed  28s (x8 over 2m2s)  persistentvolume-controller  storageclass.storage.k8s.io "manual" not found
```

Below are my questions that i am hoping to get answers/pointers to -

1. The above warning, storage class could not be found, do i need to
   create one? If so, can you tell me why and how? or any pointer. (Somehow this link misses to state that - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/)
2. Notice the PV has storage capacity of 10Gi and PVC with request capacity of 1Gi, but still PVC was bound with 10Gi capacity? Can't i share the same PV capacity with other PVCs?

For question 2) If i have to create different PVs for different PVC with the required capacity, do i have to create storageclass as-well? Or same storage class and use selectors to select corresponding PV?

Comment: Is the issue still actual?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was trying to reproduce all behavior to answer all your questions. However, I don't have access to DigitalOcean, so I tested it on GKE.

> The above warning, storage class could not be found, do i need to
> create one?

According to the documentation and best practices, it is highly recommended to create a `storageclass` and later create PV / PVC based on it. However, there is something called "manual provisioning". Which you did in this case.

Manual provisioning is when you need to manually create a PV first, and then a PVC with matching `spec.storageClassName:` field. Examples:

- If you create a PVC without `default storageclass`, `PV` and `storageClassName` parameter (afaik `kubeadm` is not providing default `storageclass`) - PVC will be stuck on `Pending` with event: `no persistent volumes available for this claim and no storage class is set`.
- If you create a PVC with `default storageclass` setup on cluster but without `storageClassName` parameter it will be created based on default `storageclass`.
- If you create a PVC with `storageClassName` parameter (somewhere in the Cloud, Minikube, or Microk8s), PVC will also get stuck `Pending` with this warning: `storageclass.storage.k8s.io "manual" not found.`
  However, if you create `PV with the same`storageClassName` parameter, it will be bound in a while.

Example:

```
$ kubectl get pv,pvc
NAME                              CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS      CLAIM   STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/task-pv-volume   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Available           manual                  4s

NAME                        STATUS    VOLUME   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/pv1   Pending                                      manual         4m12s

...

kubectl get pv,pvc
NAME                              CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM         STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/task-pv-volume   10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    default/pv1   manual                  9s

NAME                        STATUS   VOLUME           CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/pv1   Bound    task-pv-volume   10Gi       RWO            manual         4m17s
```

The disadvantage of `manual provisioning` is that you have to create PV for each PVC (only 1:1 pairings will work). If you use `storageclass`, you can just create `PVC`.

> If so, can you tell me why and how? or any pointer.

You can use [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/) examples or check [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/). As you are using a Cloud provider with default `storageclass` (or `sc` for short) set up for you, you can export it to a yaml file by: 
`$ kubectl get sc -o yaml >> storageclass.yaml`
(you will then need to clean it up, removing unique metadata, before you can reuse it).

Or, if you have more than one `sc`, you have to specify which one. Names of `storageclass` can be obtained by 
 `$ kubectl get sc`.
Later you can refer to [K8s API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.15/#storageclass-v1-storage-k8s-io) to customize your `storageclass`.

> Notice the PV has storage capacity of 10Gi and PVC with request
> capacity of 1Gi, but still PVC was bound with 10Gi capacity?

You created manually a PV with 10Gi and the PVC requested 1Gi. As PVC and PV are bound 1:1 to each other, PVC searched for a PV which meets all conditions and has bound to it. PVC ("pv1") requested 1Gi and the PV ("task-pv-volume") met those requirements, so Kubernetes bound them. Unfortunately much of the space was wasted in this case.

> Can't i share the same PV capacity with other PVCs

Unfortunately, you cannot bind more than 1 PVC to the same PV as the relationship between PVC and PV is 1:1, but you can configure many pods or deployments to use the same PVC (within the same namespace).

I can advise you to look at [this SO case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798267/kubernetes-persistent-volume-access-modes-readwriteonce-vs-readonlymany-vs-read), as it explains `AccessMode` specifics very well.

> If i have to create different PVs for different PVC with the required
> capacity, do i have to create storageclass as-well? Or same storage
> class and use selectors to select corresponding PV?

As I mentioned before, if you create PV manually with a specific size and a PVC bound to it, which requests less storage, the extra space will be wasted. So, you have to create PV and PVC with the same resource request, or let `storageclass` adjust the storage based on the PVC request.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, you have to create  storage class, [check](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes), but I guess `digital-ocean` provide default storage class, you can check it with: 
   `kubectl get storageclasses`
2. You can share one PV, but only in `read-only` access, if you need write access for all pods you have to create multiple PV, [check](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes)

Comment: "but only in" --- how about `ReadWriteMany`? Not to say they use `hostPath` which supports neither.

Answer (score 0):

IMO the question was a bit prematurely specialized to sharing a single `pv` rather than a single `storageclass` (the latter being perfectly re-usable between namespaces and pods).

More info: [using dynamic provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/#using-dynamic-provisioning).