# Kubernetes On-Prem Statefulset Pods - ELF Stack

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am trying to implement ELF stack on our Kubernetes setup running in our DC location. K8s is made up of 3 masters and 3 worker nodes. Currently, I have created and implemented headless service for ElasticSearch module and proceeding to run ElasticSearch pods on the cluster in Statefulset mode.
Below is the YAML code -

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: es-cluster
  namespace: kube-logging
spec:
  serviceName: elasticsearch
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: elasticsearch
        image: elasticsearch:7.4.2
        resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 1000m
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: rest
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: inter-node
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
        env:
          - name: cluster.name
            value: k8s-logs
          - name: node.name
            valueFrom:
              fieldRef:
                fieldPath: metadata.name
          - name: discovery.seed_hosts
            value: "es-cluster-0.elasticsearch,es-cluster-1.elasticsearch,es-cluster-2.elasticsearch"
          - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
            value: "es-cluster-0,es-cluster-1,es-cluster-2"
          - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      initContainers:
      - name: fix-permissions
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 1000:1000 /usr/share/elasticsearch/data"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - name: increase-vm-max-map
        image: busybox
        command: ["sysctl", "-w", "vm.max_map_count=262144"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
      - name: increase-fd-ulimit
        image: busybox
        command: ["sh", "-c", "ulimit -n 65536"]
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 5Gi
```

Problems -

- Though K8s starts 2 pods, only one POD is consuming PV/PVC and
  another pods is waiting with an error "pod has unbound immediate
  PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 3 times)"
- Do we have need to have Persistent Volume first?
- Can we run 3 replica Statefulset pods of ElasticSearch to use same
  VolumeMounts within On-Prem kubernetes?

Any help is highly appreciated -

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `Kubeadm`.

> Though K8s starts 2 pods, only one POD is consuming PV/PVC and another pods is waiting with an error "pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 3 times)"

If you are using [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) you need to know that It creates pods 0 up through N-1. Also It creates it one by one and pod before must running correctly. So in your case: 1st pod bounded to PV and is running correctly. StatefulSet wants to create second Pod, but it cannot bound to PV, Pod is in `Pending` state. As this pod is not working correctly, statefulset is not creating another one.

Usually `On-Prem` or `Minikube` have `default` template for `storageclass`.

Using Minikube it would like like:

```
$ kubectl get sc
NAME                 PROVISIONER                AGE
standard (default)   k8s.io/minikube-hostpath   21m
```

or GKE

```
$ kubectl get sc
NAME                 PROVISIONER            AGE
standard (default)   kubernetes.io/gce-pd   25d
```

Because of this default `storageClass` you can only `PersistentVolumeClaim` and Kubernetes automatically will create `PersistentVolume` with required resources.

However `Kubeadm` don't have definied `default storageclass`. It mean that you need to create `PersistentVolume` and `PersistentVolumeClaim` manually.

In [Persistent Volume docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#binding), especially in `Binding` chapter you will find information:

> Once bound, PersistentVolumeClaim binds are exclusive, regardless of how they were bound. A **PVC to PV binding is a one-to-one mapping.**

You can check [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57839938/kubernetes-pvcs-sharing-a-single-pv) for more information.

> Do we have need to have Persistent Volume first?

Yes, you need to specify resources in PV. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#persistent-volumes) you have example with PV.

> Can we run 3 replica Statefulset pods of ElasticSearch to use same VolumeMounts within On-Prem kubernetes?

Yes, pods can share VolumeMounts however each pod need to have own PVC.

**In Addition**

You could consider create `default` storage class.

In your Yaml you have `accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]`. It will allow **only one node** use this PV. 
Good explanation of this you can [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798267/kubernetes-persistent-volume-access-modes-readwriteonce-vs-readonlymany-vs-read).

I was not able to create this `sts` using `elasticsearch:7.4.2` image. Newest version is `elasticsearch:7.5.0`.

You can also check [this](https://medium.com/@zhimin.wen/persistent-volume-claim-for-statefulset-8050e396cc51) article.