# How to create a PV and PVC which is accessible by multiple pods and cronjobs in Kubernetes on a local setup

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volume-claims

I am trying to create a `PV` and `PVC` which is accessible by a `pod` and a `cronjob` too on the same `node`.

Currently I am using the following `yaml` file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: wwwroot
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "wwwroot"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  labels:
    app: wwwroot
  name: wwwroot
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
status: {}
```

in the `statefulSet`

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  labels:
    app: web
  name: web
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: web
  serviceName: web
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: web
        image: xy:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /app/wwwroot
          name: wwwroot
          subPath: tempwwwroot
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: xy
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: wwwroot
      spec:
        accessModes: ["ReadWriteOnce"]
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 100Gi
```

This works fine with the `pods`, but I have a `cronjob` that needs to access the same wwwroot `PV`.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  labels:
    app: import
  name: import
spec:
  schedule: "09 16 * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:  
          containers:
          - name: import
            image: xy:latest
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /app/wwwroot
              name: wwwroot
              subPath: tempwwwroot
          imagePullSecrets:
           - name: xy
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: wwwroot
            persistentVolumeClaim:
              claimName: wwwroot
```

To the best of my knowledge, you cannot bind these `PV`s to a folder on the host machine like in `Docker` (which would be nice, but I can live with that). When I run a `kubectl get pvc` with the following setup, it seem to use the same `PVC` name wwwroot, but clearly it is not. I have `/bin/bash`-d into the `pod` created by the `cronjob` and the wwwroot folder does not contain the files from the web `pod` wwwroot folder.

Any idea what am I doing wrong? Also what is the best option the create `PV`/`PVC`s on a local 1 `node` `Kubernetes` setup? I was also thinking about to create a `NFS share` on the host for easier access to the files.

Also when first created the `PV`/`PVC` and deployed the web `statefulSet`, the web `pod` should populate the wwwroot `PV` with CSS and JS files, but seems like when it bounds to the `PV`, it deletes everything from that folder and I have to manually copy those files again. Any workaround on that?

Answer (score 2):

You are mounting pv on two pod created and using pv by setting accessModes: ReadWriteOnce

You can check them below.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes

Also instant of local you can use storage class NFS volume which can give you read-write-many. I am not sure Storage class local provide it as it is not in official documents. Chk below
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/

P.S. Never use storage class in actual deployment as node in k8s come and go.

Comment: ReadWriteOnce -- the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node. These pods are on a single node.

Comment: Documentation do same node. I haven't tried but people do day it mountable by one pod refer this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57798267/kubernetes-persistent-volume-access-modes-readwriteonce-vs-readonlymany-vs-read