# file that is shared between two different pods during deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I have scenario when my cluster consist of two microservices.

In service **A** i have .CSV(15MB) file, which also is needed in service **B**.

I don't want to place this file two times in each repo.

During deployment of service **A** I want to place this .csv file in some kind of shared volume, that pod containing service **B** can consume and process it.
Any ideas and best practices how to do it?

Best regards

Comment: At that relatively small size, if the data is immutable, build it into both images, and it not, retrieve it using something like an HTTP call at startup time.  Trying to share files in a multi-node environment is always tricky, and Kubernetes doesn't really solve the various issues on its own.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution would be to build the file into the docker image.

Answer (score 1):

If you need both microservice that can read and write to a file, then you need a `sharedStorage` that supports the `ReadWriteMany` accessMode. There are a couple of options in Kubernetes like:

- NFS
- CephFS
- Glusterfs

You could find more on this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693529/how-to-share-storage-between-kubernetes-pods).

Another solution would be using object storages like `s3`.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to set it in the docker image, you can use the **initcontainer** to download when POD starts. You can set the file into the **hostPath** when **service A** starting.

When you say **service A** has file not sure if it's in the **repo** or it's part of **Docker image** build. If not part of the repo and it's stored at some central place like Bucket you can download it when **service B** starts with **initcontainer**.

Example downloading file and set & share to hostpath:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: init-demo
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    volumeMounts:
    - name: save-data
      mountPath: /data-dir
  initContainers:
  - name: install
    image: ubuntu
    command: ['curl', 'download-link-path >', '/tmp/file.csv']
    volumeMounts:
    - name: save-data
      mountPath: "/data-dir"
  dnsPolicy: Default
  volumes:
  - name: save-data
    hostPath:
      path: /data-dir
      type: Directory
```

other option is to set the shared file system which multiple PODs can attach and use same time. **[ReadWriteMany](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57798369/5525824)** or **[ReadOnlyMany](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57798369/5525824)** option.

- [Minio](https://min.io/)

is very good option to use for above scenario.